# iOS core location heading and course changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I am working on an app in which I show the location and direction a plane is heading when flying.  I also want to then show labels of the cities one is flying by using augmented reality.  I have everything set up and it was working ok when sitting still or driving in a car but when I used it on a plane something weird happened.
When sitting at the gate with the door open or closed the heading of the location icon shows the correct direction when the device is in landscape mode (home button to right). If I rotate the device to the right the plane icon rotates to the right the appropriate amount.  Same with left.  This is important because when I rotate the phone to the right or left and open the camera for augmented reality the correct cities show up in the correct place.  This works completely fine even when we are taxiing on the runway.
However when we take off the function changes. Now no matter what way I change the rotation of the device the plane icon always points in the direction the plane is moving.
I am trying to figure out why this happens and was wondering if this is because at the slower speed sitting still or taxiing core location is using HEADING whereas when we take off enough information is being gather to use COURSE information.
I don't thing this is happening because I am in a faraday cage because it wouldn't work when at the gate or taxiing.
If it is in fact using Heading/Course information how do I compensate so the city labels are where they are supposed to be instead of constantly moving to the front of the plane?
am getting the user latitude, longitude and altitude and the correct heading to the cities so all that is working fine.  It is just heading/course problem.

Here is some code just to show I have these things going.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

Can I use gyroscope to tell what direction the phone is pointing and add it to the heading/course to get the labels in the correct place if the speed is above a certain amount?
Has anyone ran into the problem and solved it?

Comment: This Apple documentation might help you:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion?language=objc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all well documented by Apple. The location manager uses your direction of motion to determine heading, and ignores phone attitude, if you are moving quickly. If you want the phone attitude independently you must use Core Motion instead.

Comment: Do you know at what speed (velocity) the change is made. Is it when speed more than 0 or 1?

Comment: Thanks used core motion and seems to work but have to wait till I fly again to see for aure